# Is there a solution to reorganize the following array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to transform this array `['1','3','+','8','0','/','5','7','0']` into `['13','+','80','/','570']`

I tried this:

```
    let valu = val.value;
    let tab1 = [];
   
   if(!isNaN(valu)) {
       
        tab1.push(valu)   
    }

   else {
       
        tab.push(tab1)
        tab1 = [];
        tab.push(valu)
       
   }
```

Comment: whatt is `val`? what is `val.value`? you would at least need some sort of a loop ...

Comment: val is from the onclick in my html code. But what i really want is to transform this array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could test if the avtual value has only digits and if the last stored valu has digits, then add the avual value. Otherwise push the value to the result set.

```js
const
    hasDigits = c => /^\d+$/.test(c),
    array = ['1', '3', '+', '8', '0', '/', '5', '7', '0'],
    result = array.reduce((r, v) => {
        if (hasDigits(v) && hasDigits(r[r.length - 1] || '')) r[r.length - 1] += v;
        else r.push(v);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```